# Can I bind POCO's to Elasticsearch hits for stronger typing?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Tweets in an index can have a structure like this (not strict JSON, just trying to convey the structure:)

```
{
  text: string
  created_at: DateTime
  mention: [
    {
      name: string
      screen_name: string
      start: int
      end: int
    }
  ],
  hashtag: [
    // multiple string/int props similar to mention
  ],
  link: [
    // multiple string/int props similar to mention
  ],
  user: {
    name: string
    screen_name: string
    profile_image_url: string
  }
}
```

I'm getting the expected hits when using the NEST client, but I was under the impression I could map POCO's to bind the results to get some stronger typing e.g.

```
public class TweetDocument
{
  public string text { get; set; }
  public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
  public List<Mention> mention { get; set; }
  public List<Hashtag> hashtag { get; set; }
  public List<Link> link { get; set; }
  public User user { get; set; }
}

public class Mention
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string screen_name { get; set; }
  public int start { get; set; }
  public int end { get; set; }
}

// ... other POCO's for Hashtag, Link and User
```

The string property `text` and DateTime property `created_at` bind ok, but the `mention`, `hashtag` and `link` properties are all null when I look at the response's hits e.g.

```
var response = client.Search<TweetDocument>(q);
var firstHit = response.Hits.Hits.FirstOrDefault();
// firstHit.Fields.hashtag, .mention, .link and .user are all null
```

I've seen some attributes, but haven't really figured out how to use them e.g. `ElasticProperty` and `ElasticType`. **How do I populate these collections from my index including the non-collection .User child property?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should totally be able to bind those.

Unless when you specify the `.Fields()` property in your `.Search()`

What happens is that your document will live under _source if you don't specify Fields the hits wil return the `_source` if you specify fields it will return the fields as an array i.e:

```
 fields: {
    mention.name: ["name1", "name2"]
 }
```

which is basically a flattened view of your original _source document.

It would help if you can paste result.ConnectionStatus.Result to see how your results look like.

Comment: I was specifying incorrect fields e.g. `mention.name` in the query instead of just `mention`. I also needed to decorate the POCO's with `ElasticType(Name="whatever")]` but I did get it to work.

Comment: You can use `.SetPropertyNameInferrer(p=>p.ToPythonCase())` on `ConnectionSettings` to globally specify how the property names look like. NEST by default camelCase's property names. This helps prevent the need to plaster attributes everywhere.